# Does multipurpose node is a good thing for scaling?

Tags: web-server, load-balancing, scaling

I have a web app with different tiers:

- database for persistence
- a couple of web servers(mongrels)
- load balancer

Now it is all running on the same host. But how can I add another server to handle higher load?

Should I separate roles (db & web) before scaling out any further?

P.S.   let's simplify the question and ignore High-Availability issues in this question.

P.P.S. database is not a bottleneck right now. I really want to add more web servers, please help

Comment: Are you asking for instructions on how to split your roles with the technologies you have, or just asking a more general question of whether you should seperate your roles (db & web) before scaling out any further?

Comment: 2Chris: good point, my mistake! It is a general question of whether you should seperate your roles (db & web) before scaling out any further.

Question has been clarified.

Comment: My similar question was closed but this one has been okay for 13 years? https://serverfault.com/questions/1157088/what-are-some-good-nginx-rate-limits-for-wordpress-websites

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@gotts: The canonical way of scaling out small websites looks something like this:

**First:** Split to 2 servers, one that runs your HTTP server & web application code (webapp), and one for your database. The database server should be optimized for database workloads, i.e. lots of RAM, fast disk I/O, fast CPU.

**Then:** Offload static file serving from the webapp server, either to a different server, or to a Content Delivery Network. Consider disabling HTTP KeepAlive on the webapp server.

**Then:** Move to a setup with at least 4 servers:

- One HTTP load balancer at the front, using consistent hashing based on source IP address.
- Behind the HTTP load balancer, 2 webapp servers.
- Behind the webapps, 1 Database server.

This [presentation by Brad Fitzpatrick shows a typical progression](http://www.usenix.org/event/usenix07/tech/slides/fitzpatrick.pdf) on its first pages. If all this is new to you, perhaps you should consider hiring a sysadmin who has done this before... :-)

Answer (score 0):

> Now it is all running on the same host

Stupid idea, or? I mean - what the heck does a LOAD BALANCER do in the list if there is only one host to start with? This is the one item that makes absolutely no sense to me.

- Separate roles first. Esepcially as the requirements are vastly different (larger DB needs a lot more IOPS which means many discs).
- Then reprogram so that multiple web servers can easily coexist.
- Finally add a load balancer if needed, or use DNS round robin.

Comment: Mongrel is a process based Ruby application server. It is common best practice in the Ruby world to place a fast HTTP server (nginx, Apache) in front of several Mongrels to add lightweight connection handling and fast static file serving.

Answer (score 0):

For security and performance, I would be inclined to push the incoming http handling
into a presentation tier (1 or more servers). Static content can be served in the
presentation tier. Also your database / business logic is less exposed to attacks.